# how to repeat entire table in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, repeat

I have a code which repeats rows while loop, but how can i repeat the entire table in while loop.
The code is

```
    $kandivli = mysql_query("SELECT ps_order_detail.product_name, sum(ps_order_detail.product_quantity) AS product_total FROM ps_order_detail JOIN ps_product ON ps_product.id_product = ps_order_detail.product_id JOIN ps_orders ON ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_detail.id_order WHERE ps_product.id_supplier = '" . $supplier_number . "' && ps_orders.current_state = '" . $status1 ."' && ps_order_detail.id_shop = 1 GROUP BY ps_order_detail.product_name");
    $ktotal = mysql_query("SELECT sum(ps_order_detail.product_quantity) AS product_total FROM ps_order_detail JOIN ps_product ON ps_product.id_product = ps_order_detail.product_id JOIN ps_orders ON ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_detail.id_order WHERE ps_product.id_supplier = '" . $supplier_number . "' && ps_orders.current_state = '" . $status1 ."' && ps_order_detail.id_shop = 1");
    $krow = mysql_fetch_array($ktotal);
    $kftotal = $krow['product_total'];
    if(mysql_num_rows($kandivli) > 0)
    {
    echo '<table border="1" align="center" class="total">';
    echo "<th>&nbsp; Product Name &nbsp;</td><th> &nbsp;Total Quantity &nbsp;</th>";


    while($kandivlirow = mysql_fetch_array($kandivli))
    {
    $kandivli_product = $kandivlirow['product_name'];
    $kandivlitotal = $kandivlirow['product_total'];
    echo '<tr>';

    echo "<td align='center'>$kandivli_product</td><tdalign='center'>$kandivlitotal</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo "<td align='center'><b>Total</b></td><td align='center'><b>$kftotal</b></td>";
    echo '</table>';
    }
    else echo "<div align='center'>No Pending orders</div>";
    ?>
```

Right now i just have 5 shops but if i add a new shop every time i have to copy paste and change this code to && ps_order_detail.id_shop = 6 then && ps_order_detail.id_shop = 7 and so on

So please if anyone shows how to repeat table. It would be grateful.
Hope my question is clear. (I want to repeat the entire table)
Regards

Amod

Ok I have Edited the code Now i get 6 tables as expected but the rows show the same data of shop one.

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once "connect.php";
?>
<?php



$supplier = mysql_query("SELECT ps_order_detail.product_name, sum(ps_order_detail.product_quantity) AS product_total, ps_supplier.name FROM ps_order_detail JOIN ps_product ON ps_product.id_product = ps_order_detail.product_id JOIN ps_supplier ON ps_supplier.id_supplier = ps_product.id_supplier JOIN ps_orders ON ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_detail.id_order WHERE ps_orders.current_state = 4 GROUP BY ps_order_detail.id_shop");



$alltotal = mysql_query("SELECT sum(ps_order_detail.product_quantity) AS producttotal FROM ps_order_detail JOIN ps_product ON ps_product.id_product = ps_order_detail.product_id JOIN ps_orders ON ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_detail.id_order WHERE ps_orders.current_state = 4 && ps_order_detail.id_shop = 11");

$ct = mysql_fetch_array($alltotal);

$ct1 = $ct['producttotal'];



while($supplierrow = mysql_fetch_array($supplier))
{
$kandivli = mysql_query("SELECT ps_order_detail.product_name, sum(ps_order_detail.product_quantity) AS product_total,ps_supplier.name FROM ps_order_detail JOIN ps_product ON ps_product.id_product = ps_order_detail.product_id JOIN ps_supplier ON ps_supplier.id_supplier = ps_product.id_supplier JOIN ps_orders ON ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_detail.id_order WHERE ps_orders.current_state = 4 GROUP BY ps_order_detail.product_name");
echo '<table border="1" align="center" class="total">';

while($kandivlirow = mysql_fetch_array($kandivli))
{

$sup = $kandivlirow['name'];
$sp = $kandivlirow['product_name'];
$spt = $kadivlirow['product_total'];
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td align='center'>$sp</td><td align='center'>$spt</td><td align='center'>$sup</td>";
echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
echo '<br>';
}
echo "<td align='center'><b>Total</b></td><td align='center'><b>$ct1</b></td>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while($kandivlirow = mysql_fetch_array($kandivli))
    {
    //Your table code 
   echo '<table border="1" align="center" class="total">';
  //Middle section 
   echo '</table>';

    }
```